# Tweepy API: What is a session object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

The [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html?highlight=session) uses an object named `session` that is not defined or explained anywhere in the documentation or the library's [tests](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/master/tests).

What is this object, and what is an example of instantiating it?

I guessed at first it was an instance of `requests.Session()`, but that doesn't come with a `.set()` method (or really make sense in context):

```
>>> import requests
>>> hasattr(requests.Session(), 'set')
False
```

There is also [no class within tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/search?q=%22def+set%28%22&unscoped_q=%22def+set%28%22) that defines a `.set()` method.

---

Excerpt from the docs:

> This call requests the token from twitter and returns to us the authorization URL where the user must be redirect to authorize us. Now if this is a desktop application we can just hang onto our OAuthHandler instance until the user returns back. In a web application we will be using a callback request. So we must store the request token in the session since we will need it inside the callback URL request. Here is a pseudo example of storing the request token in a session:
>
> `session.set('request_token', auth.request_token)`

Comment: I think they're saying `session` can be any key/value store. Anything from python's builtin dict, to redis, other nosql stores, etc. Disclaimer: I know very little about tweepy, I used it once about a year ago and had the exact same question

Comment: @MattMessersmith That makes sense as I've seen it used with Redis to keep track of number of calls on certain keys

Comment: I'll put my previous comment as an answer since it got some upvotes and no one has answered yet who knows more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the docs are saying `session` can be *any* key/value store, but they are not particularly clear in this regard. So `session` can be anything from python's builtin `dict`, to redis, other nosql stores, etc. The implementation details and what class the `session` object actually is are left to the user.

Disclaimer: I know very little about tweepy and fully admit this is some guesswork. I used it once about a year ago and had the exact same question.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted this on the Tweepy support Discord chat page, will accept if I don't get a response.  But would be nice to have any semblance of an official source...